# Почему запрос выдает пустой результат?

Tags: firebird

Пытаюсь узнать существует ли таблица `mytable` в базе данных, результат пуст.
Ошибок выполнения запроса нет. Таблица такая в базе существует. `Firebird 2.5`

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'mytable'
```

Comment: И вы давали этот запрос без условия where и убедились, что таблица не только есть, но и написана такими же буквами (а не большими например)

Comment: Выдержка из документации: Следующие имена с точки зрения системы являются одинаковыми:

fullname
FULLNAME
FuLlNaMe
FullName

Comment: Перепроверьте регистр в имени таблицы. Если `create table mytable` был без кавычек - создалась таблица MYTABLE

Comment: Да, с точки зрения системы имена одинаковые, потому что система перед поиском имен приводит их к одному регистру и обычно это именно верхний регистр. так что вы при поиске должны сделать то же самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Следующие имена с точки зрения системы являются одинаковыми:
>
> fullname FULLNAME FuLlNaMe FullName

Фактически это обозначает только то, что создастся таблица FULLNAME.

Всё ещё есть возможность создать таблицу `fullName` с помощью так называемого `<delimited name>`:

```
create table "fullName"
```

Т.к. поле `RDB$RELATION_NAME` системной таблицы `RDB$RELATIONS` имеет регистро-зависимый collation - нужно указывать правильный регистр имени таблицы при поиске(либо приводить к case-insensitive collate перед сравнением).

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MYTABLE';
SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = upper('mytable');
SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE upper(RDB$RELATION_NAME) = upper('mytable'); -- также найдёт "myTable"
```